# Не могу добавить адрес электронной почты в sqllte3

Tags: python, email, sqlite3

Не могу добавить адрес электронной почты в sqlite3, Python

sqlite3.OperationalError: near "@gmail": syntax error

```
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO user_emails (chat_id, email, name) VALUES (" + str(message.chat.id) + ","+ message.text + "," + message.from_user.first_name+")")
        conn.close()
```

Comment: Используй одинарные кавычки внутри запроса. И какой у тебя тип поля?

Comment: Так не кто не делает, используйте подстановку.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте параметризированные  запросы: вместо значений подставьте в строку `'?'`, а сами значения в виде кортежа вторым аргументом передайте. Посмотрите в документации на любой вызов execute с переменными:

```
cur.execute("select ?", ("value",))
```

это равнозначно:

```
cur.execute("select 'value'")
```

с той разницей, что параметризированный запрос автоматически экранирует переданные значения.

Answer (score 1):

Помогла вот такая реализация:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO user_emails (chat_id, email, name) VALUES (:chat_id, :email, :name)",
               {"chat_id": str(message.chat.id),"email": message.text,"name":message.from_user.first_name})
```

Спасибо за ответы, натолкнули на мысль.